# jQuery how to find class of an element which has a particular action

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to find the class of an element which matches a particular pattern.
Basically what I am trying to do is add custom text to the end of form in a framework based product.

All instances of the product have the same

```
<form action="/cart" method="post" class="...">
</form>
```

I need to find the class of the form element in each such instance so that I can traverse to the last child and add my piece of text.
Is it possible using jQuery alone?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you can find any element by an attribute by wrapping it with `[]`

`$('[action="/cart"]')`

This is where the attribute equals the value, but you can do contains by adding `*` before the `=` like so:

`$('[action*=cart]')`

Here's a list of attribute selectors:

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Then get the attribute for class:

`$('[action="/cart"]').attr('class')`

Quick sample here:

https://jsfiddle.net/op7bv8Lu/

---

If you want to get the last element you can add `:last` to the selector.

`$('[action*=cart]:last').attr('class')`

Again, sample here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xzpag6up/